# How to read the worksheet name in laravel Maatwebsite excel

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am having the excel sheet with multiple worksheets in it, I want to get the name of the worksheet which is currently active

Answer (score 9):

I think `$event->getSheet()->getTitle()` should work. You can also use events also.

```
class HImport1 implements ToCollection, WithHeadingRow, WithEvents
{
    public $sheetNames;
    public $sheetData;
    
    public function __construct(){
        $this->sheetNames = [];
        $this->sheetData = [];
    }

    public function collection(Collection $collection)
    {
        $this->sheetData[] = $collection;
    }

    public function registerEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            BeforeSheet::class => function(BeforeSheet $event) {
                $this->sheetNames[] = $event->getSheet()->getTitle();
            } 
        ];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In version 3.1, the API has changed slightly. You'll have to call `getDelegate()` before getting the title. Building off of @Satendra Rawat answer...

```php
public function registerEvents(): array
{
    return [
        BeforeSheet::class => function (BeforeSheet $event) {
            $this->sheetNames[] = $event->getSheet()->getDelegate()->getTitle();
        }
    ];
}
```

Comment: is there anyway to skip a sheet and getting it data based on the checking of the sheet name against in DB